# Mongodb Pagination after aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

- I want merge **metadata** and **metadatax** to display result
  properly, as you can see I have used `$match` multiple times to get
  proper result after aggregate.
- I also need  `total_pages` in metadata, How to implement this formula `Math.ceil(total_items/limit)`.

**Note:** The code is working properly but need
   to optimize the logic.

```
db.collection('cms_brands').aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [{ $match: {title:"clue brand"} }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }],
      metadatax: [ { $count: "total" }, { $addFields: { page: 0 } }],
      metadata: [ { $match: {title:"clue brand"} }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }, {$group: { _id: "$title", count: { $sum: 1 } }} ],

    }
  }
]).toArray()
    .then((items) => { return { statusCode: 200, body: items }; })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('=> an error occurred: ', err);
      return { statusCode: 500, body: 'error' };
    });
```

**Actual response :**

```
[
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "_id": "5e91d2c4a3fda138bcdbfd82",
          "title": "clue brand"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5e91d2dea3fda138bcdbfd83",
          "title": "clue brand"
        }
      ],
      "metadatax": [
        {
          "total": 3,
          "page": 0
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "_id": "clue brand",
          "count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Expected response :**

```
[
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "_id": "5e91d2c4a3fda138bcdbfd82",
          "title": "clue brand"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5e91d2dea3fda138bcdbfd83",
          "title": "clue brand"
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "total": 3,
          "page": 0,
          "_id": "clue brand",
          "count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change few things, try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      metadatax: [{ $count: "total" }, { $addFields: { page: 0 } }],
      metadata: [
        { $match: { title: "clue brand" } },
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 10 },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$title",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$metadata" },
  {
    $project: {
      data: "$metadata.data",
      metadata: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          { _id: "$metadata._id", count: "$metadata.count",total_pages: { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$metadatax.total",  0 ] } , 8 ] } } },
          { $arrayElemAt: ["$metadatax", 0] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sxSrETqReGQ)

**Updates :**

1. You don't need this `data: [{ $match: {title:"clue brand"} }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }]` additional step in `$facet`, can be replaced with `data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }` in `$group` of `metadata`.
2. Also as `metadata` will always be an array of single object - instead of being an array, I would suggest it to be an object for easy access in code. Just in case if you need it as an array all you need is to wrap `$mergeObjects` in array in `$project`.

*Like this :*

```
  metadata: [{
    $mergeObjects: [
      { _id: "$metadata._id", count: "$metadata.count" },
      { $arrayElemAt: ["$metadatax", 0] }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: When I try to run this query on my side, It says :  **MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'**

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : What is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.5.5

Comment: @TahaFarooqui: On MongoDB v`3.6` below try this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/j2ES1-R8A64) but I would suggest to upgrade your version asap cause `3.5.5` is too old & newer version is `4.2`. Instead of `$mergeObjects` you need to do it manually : `{
    $unwind: "$metadatax"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: "$metadata.data",
      "metadata": {
        _id: "$metadata._id",
        count: "$metadata.count",
        page: "$metadatax.page",
        total: "$metadatax.total"
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Perfect!! This one is working perfectly: https://mongoplayground.net/p/j2ES1-R8A64

Comment: How do I apply this formula to get total pages: `Math.ceil(total_items/limit)`

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : Try these `$ceil` & `$divide` aggregation operators (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/index.html)

Comment: I have noticed one problem, The total count before aggregate. It should work after aggregate. If I copy and paste the `{
          $match: {
            title: {$eq: "clue bran"}
          }
          
        }` in `metadatax` than it gave me the correct result. The issue is `limit` in metadata.

Comment: I have another question, suppose if there is no value in title, is it possible to display all data using same query?

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : nope you can't !!

Comment: I am using M10 cluster and have 105K records now. This query takes at least a minute to show data. Can you guess what I am missing here?

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : There can be multiple reasons why a query is slow!
1) Try to add indexes & check index utilization using `explain`. 2) All docs are being pulled from disk at `$facet` step which is expensive, adding `$match` or `$project` early can help but in ur case you may try to split ur query into 2. 3) Try to check cluster metrics in Atlas to see if any-other queries are making ur DB slow at the same time.